# How do you pass an object into a new form?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Why doesn't my car object pass into my ViewCarForm?

A car gets passed into InventoryItemPanel.

```
public class InventoryItemPanel extends JPanel{
Car car;
Button button = new Button("View More Details");



public InventoryItemPanel(Car car){

    this.car = car;

    // executes ButtonActionPerformed when button is clicked.
    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    add(button);


}

public void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    new ViewCarForm(car).setVisible(true);
}                                         
}
```

The button when clicked is then supposed to pass the same car to ViewCarForm.

```
public class ViewCarForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Car car;


public ViewCarForm() {
    initComponents();
}

public ViewCarForm(Car car){
   new ViewCarForm().setVisible(true);
   jLabel.setText(car.getMake());
}
}
```

However, the label in ViewCarForm does not get updated by the car object, so I assume that it is not passing through?

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JPanel`) with AWT (e.g. `Button`) components without good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at what this constructor is doing:

```
public ViewCarForm(Car car){
   new ViewCarForm().setVisible(true); // (A)
   jLabel.setText(car.getMake());      // (B)
}
```

- On line (A) you create a new ViewCarForm object -- and you do so within the ViewCarForm constructor, not something that I recommend that you do, since now you have **two** ViewCarForm instances, the original one, and a new one that you display.
- On line (B) you set the text of a JLabel, a variable of the **first and non-displayed ViewCarForm instance** (I'm guessing that it's a variable of this class -- you never show us the variable declaration or instantiation. OK this will set the JLabel text of a **non-displayed** GUI, meanwhile the second ViewCarForm instance, the one that you **do** display, has no change to the text of its JLabel.
- You **don't** call `this()` or `initComponents()` within the 2nd constructor, and so the code from the first default constructor, including the `initComponents();` call, is never called, and so components are never properly laid out when this constructor is called.

Solution: **don't do this**, don't create two ViewCarForm instances, especially from within the same class's constructor. The only reason you don't have a stackoverflow error is because your class has two constructors, but even without the stackoverflow, it's insanity to do this. Create only one instance and set its JLabel text. **Get rid of line (A)**

Also, if the ViewCarForm is a secondary window, it shouldn't even be a JFrame but rather it should be a JDialog, either modal or non-modal depending on your need.

Also, you only init components in one ViewCarForm constructor and not in the other. So the JLabel will not show up in the second constructor/instance.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InventoryFoo extends JPanel {
    private static final Car FIRST_CAR = new Car("Honda");
    private InventoryItemPanel inventoryItemPanel = new InventoryItemPanel(FIRST_CAR);

    public InventoryFoo() {

        inventoryItemPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Inventory Item"));

        add(inventoryItemPanel);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        InventoryFoo mainPanel = new InventoryFoo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("InventoryFoo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class InventoryItemPanel extends JPanel {
    Car car;

    // Button button = new Button("View More Details"); // should be a JButton
    JButton button = new JButton("View More Details"); // should be a JButton

    public InventoryItemPanel(Car car) {

        this.car = car;

        // executes ButtonActionPerformed when button is clicked.
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        add(button);

    }

    public void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // new ViewCarPanel(car).setVisible(true);

        // get current JFrame
        Window thisJFrame = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        // Create a non-modal JDialog
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(thisJFrame, "Car Make", ModalityType.MODELESS);
        // create new viewCarPanel
        ViewCarPanel viewCarPanel = new ViewCarPanel(car);
        // add to dialog
        dialog.add(viewCarPanel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(thisJFrame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
// better for this to be a JPanel
class ViewCarPanel extends JPanel {
    Car car;
    private JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();

    public ViewCarPanel() {
        add(new JLabel("Car Make:"));
        add(jLabel);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 80));
    }

    public ViewCarPanel(Car car) {
        // so that we init components from the default constructor
        this(); 

        // new ViewCarPanel().setVisible(true);
        jLabel.setText(car.getMake());
    }
}
```

```
class Car {

    private String make;

    public Car(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return this.make;
    }

}
```